# data length issue from SQL Server to Oracle with non english characher

Tags: sql, oracle

we have 2 applications. One application uses SQL Server as the backend and the other application uses Oracle.

In the first application the user can enter some information and the 2nd application gets the data from SQL Server and insert it into oracle.

The problem is that the user can enter in any language following table shows sample data

Table in SQL Server

[image]

For instance user has entered Chinese characters in address field and length is 10,

Oracle Table

[image]

Address is not inserted here because length of address exceeds to 12, in oracle special character considering as 3 length.

I want to substring character (with non english and with english). How can I achieve that? I have written function which written number of special character.

[image]

how to get only 5 charachters from @nstring

Comment: Please do **not** post code as [screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @nstring NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'理,551'
declare @lenSQL int = len(@nstring)
declare @oracleLen int = @lenSQL +(2 * [dbo].[CountNonEnglishfromString](@nstring)) 

declare @OracleMaxLen int =  5; -- change as per len required 


declare @newString nvarchar(max);
if(@OracleMaxLen < @oracleLen)
begin 
declare @olen int =0
        declare @count int =1;
            WHILE ( @count <= @lenSQL)
                BEGIN        
                       declare @ch nvarchar(1) =(SELECT SUBSTRING(@nstring,@count,@count) AS ExtractString); 
                       declare @isSpecialChar int = [dbo].[CountNonEnglishfromString](@ch)
                          if(@isSpecialChar = 1)
                              begin  
                                    set @olen = @olen+3;  
                              end   
                          else 
                                begin   
                                       set  @olen = @olen+1;  
                                 end  
                          if(@OracleMaxLen < @olen)
                           begin  
                                break
                            end  
                           set  @newString =CONCAT(@newString , @ch)
                        set @count = @count +1
                End 
End 
else
begin 
 set @newString = @nstring
end 

select isnull(@newString,'') as 'new string';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the column in Oracle as `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`. That changes the length semantics from bytes to characters. So the column will be able to accept 10 characters not just 10 bytes, which might be to short if there are special characters in the string.